# Oracle WHERE clause ( AND , OR operators)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Friends 
while executing where clause in Oracle SQL suppose  I have

```
UPDATE schema1.TBL_SCHEMA1_PROCESS_FEED F
                 SET F.TBL_SCHEMA1_PROCESS_LINE_ID      = V_LINE_ID,
                     F.TBL_SCHEMA1_PROCESS_LINE_TYPE_ID = V_LINE_TYPE_ID,
                     F.TBL_SCHEMA1_PROCESS_LINE_SUB_TYPE_ID = V_SUB_TYPE_ID,
               WHERE F.CURR_DATE = V_CURR_DATE  
               AND   F.NEXT_DATE = V_NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE OR F.NEXT_DATE IS NULL;
```

How this code can be optimized for the condition

```
F.NEXT_DATE = V_NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE OR F.NEXT_DATE IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is your problem?

Comment: In my WHERE Clause IS the     AND   F.NEXT_DATE = V_NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE OR F.NEXT_DATE IS NULL; can be written in another way I mean since It is using both AND and OR Operators on the same column . Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that your actual `where` clause? Do you mean it to be:

```
WHERE F.CURR_DATE = V_CURR_DATE  
  AND ( F.NEXT_DATE = V_NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE 
        OR F.NEXT_DATE IS NULL )
```

If so then you *need* an index, unique if possible, on `curr_date`.

If you're not satisfied that this provides a large enough improvement in the execution time then think about extending it to `curr_date, next_date`. Don't create a larger index if you don't need to.

You might also consider chaning your conditions slightly, though I doubt it would make much, if any, difference.

```
WHERE F.CURR_DATE = V_CURR_DATE  
  AND NVL(F.NEXT_DATE, V_NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE) = V_NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE
```

The best possible option is, to update using the [`rowid`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns008.htm#SQLRF00254). Without a lot more information it's impossible to know if you're in a situation where this might be possible but as the `rowid` is a unique address in the table it *always* is quicker than indexes, when updating a single row. If you're collecting data from this table then populating your variables before writing back to the table then this would be possible.

Are those your actual schema and table names... if they are then why not think about chosing something more descriptive?

Comment: Thanks , Since the there would be a large no of records getting updated so using WHERE F.CURR_DATE = V_CURR_DATE     AND ( F.NEXT_DATE = V_NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE          OR F.NEXT_DATE IS NULL )   OR just using WHERE F.CURR_DATE = V_CURR_DATE     AND NVL(F.NEXT_DATE, V_NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE) = V_NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE   is better as the no of records to be updated could go around 100000

Comment: Sorry @ronan, is that a question? I doubt using either query would make much difference. What will definitely make a difference is _indexes_.